# Mouse wheel in Ubuntu for Windows not working

Tags: 14.04, mouse, windows-10

I'm using the Ubuntu for Windows feature of Windows 10, and I can't get my mouse wheel to scroll up and down. I'm not sure if this is an Ubuntu issue, or a compatibility issue between Windows and the Ubuntu shell. The Ubuntu shell is terminal only, no UI -- is there even a way to enable mouse scrolling with this?

*update*: I've noticed this seems to only be an issue for things like `less` -- if I'm doing a `tail -f` on a file, the scroll wheel works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no mechanical problems with the mouse wheel, scrolling terminal output with a mouse wheel should work in any Ubuntu terminal session.  This includes viewing files with less and more.

How Ubuntu for Windows is handled by Win10 would probably be best answered by Microsoft Support.  Based on the results of your testing I'm guessing that mouse wheel support is limited in that environment.